# When I look at a map, is the Y co-ordinate at my head or my feet?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing Minecraft on the Xbox, and the only way to identify current position is by looking at the map.

The X and Z co-ordinates are what they are, as you only take up one block in those dimensions. However, I'm unsure how to interpret the Y co-ordinate. Is it at my head or my feet?

I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72441/using-the-map-item-on-minecraft-xbox-360), which answers a lot about Xbox maps, but not the Y in relation to my character.

This matters for the purpose of finding proper depth for optimal ore-hunting, plus it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PC version, pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> would show the Y coordinate at eye level, having a value about 1.5 blocks higher than where the feet are.  In later patches, the Y coordinate at feet level was added to this information.

Considering the 360 version isn't as updated as the PC version, you're probably looking at the eye-level coordinates.

Again, having only a 1.5 block difference from eye to foot level, you could try making a tower to the sky.  Since the height limit is 127, eye level should be 129, rounded up from 128.5.

Comment: I did a tower jump up to the top of the playable area. When I couldn't add any more blocks, my map said Y: 128. I'm not sure if that supports your claim or not.

Comment: Then I would still say that it is eye level.  The game may have rounded down.

Comment: I did some more tests - involving finding lava pools near bedrock. After verifying that they most commonly occur at Y = 10, and finding my map to read Y = 12 while standing on the block at the same height as the pool, I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in my experience, in the XBox version, the Y coordinate is for your foot level.

In the PC version it seems to list both your foot level and eye level, but in my tests (at least of a few versions ago), the XBox Y coordinate was for your foot level.